# Incorrect url in omniture dashboad My Reports

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, adobe-analytics

I'm looking to implement Omniture into my site. I've been provided some javascript code but not sure if I need this in the page or if I just need to supply some extra params along in s object properties.
While viewing the report in Omniture dashboard, i see "undefined:undefined:mysite name". Does anyone know how to avoid the undefined error?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with Omniture reports.

Those values are coming from whatever javascript code you have that is populating Omniture's  `s.pageName` variable on your page.

Likely what is happening is you have code that attempts to build the value based off other javascript variables that for whatever reason are not being defined, so `s.pageName` is getting `undefined` as a value for them.

Based on the "file:////C:" portion of the value, my guess here is that your `s.pageName` variable is probably built by parsing the URL, and it's not parsing correctly because the page was viewed from a browser locally. For example, perhaps one of the "undefined" values is based off `location.hostname` or simlar. But if someone has a local copy of the page on their computer and views it in the browser, there would be no hostname (unless they went out of their way to map one in hosts file.. but then if that were the case, you likely wouldn't have that file:////C: value), which could cause `s.pageName` to show `undefined` for it, depending on the actual logic of your code.

But, that is just an example. I don't actually insight into your code to know what it's actually doing.  If you post the javascript code responsible for populating `s.pageName`, I may be able to offer more details about it, but that's basically what it boils down to: attempting to assign undefined variable(s) to `s.pageName`

Comment: thanks @Crayon for the reply.Its a single page application so i am setting the s.pageName on every section pageshow. The s.pageName shows the exact pagename on section loads. Still the issue exists. Anything else to watch out for?

Comment: Dig around your site and test in the Javascript console by executing "s.pageName" which will print the current value for page-name.

Comment: Also, there is a plug-in for FireBug called "OmniBug" and also a tool provided by Adobe called "Adobe Debugger" which can be downloaded from their help section. These will help you debug.